# worker_threads module isnot running with PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2, node-worker-threads

I'm using Express, from within `app.js` I'm calling a worker thread which is in another file named `service.js`. everything runs smoothly when I run it normally via `node app.js`, but as soon as I switch to PM2, `pm2 start app.js` nothing happens. it won't even try to call the `service.js` file. **I'm running node v17.4.0** on an Ubuntu 18.04. any idea on what might be going on?

app.js

```
// app.js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')

function runService(workerData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./service', { workerData });
    worker.on('message', resolve);
    worker.on('error', reject);
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
    })
  })
}

async function run() {
  const result = await runService('world')
  console.log(result);
}

run().catch(err => console.error(err))
```

service.js

```
//service.js
const { workerData, parentPort } = require('worker_threads')

// You can do any heavy stuff here, in a synchronous way
// without blocking the "main thread"
parentPort.postMessage({ hello: workerData })
```